# Optimal server configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, server-setup, system-configuration

What should be the optimal server configuration for magento 1.9.1.1 with following details:

`1. ~15k products
2. ~100 product attributes
3. Product names > 150 characters
4. url almost as same as product names
5. About 50 categories
6. ~12 custom modules (including one marketplace and dropship module)
7 Database size ~2 GB`

Answer (score -1):

There many possible options: it depands on your requirements.

**Sizing up your own requirements**

As a rule of thumb, it is possible to

Directly correlate your traffic levels to your CPU requirements
Directly correlate your CPU requirements to RAM requirements
Directly correlate your MySQL storage to RAM requirements
CPU Selection

**First start by sizing up your traffic.**

```
A standard Magento demo store is capable of delivering roughly 230 uniques per GHz, per hour.

A typical web store, with admin user activity, development activity, product addition/deletion can see this degrade by around 100%, to 115 uniques per GHz, per hour.

A store with a poorly built/heavy template can further reduce the figure by another 100-200%, to 50 uniques per GHz, per hour.
```

Using these numbers, you can work out exactly what you need in terms of CPU resource.

Eg. If you have 4,025 sustained unique visitors/day - you need 28GHz total CPU resource (ie. 8 Cores @ 3.5GHz, or 12 Cores @ 2.3GHz)

**The other important detail is the speed of the CPU, it is possible to have:**

```
A slow page load time and low concurrency support (low clock speed CPU (GHz), few cores)

A fast page load time, but low concurrency support (high clock speed CPU (GHz), few cores)

A slow page load time, but high concurrency support (low clock speed CPU (GHz), lots of cores)
```

A fast page load time and high concurrency support (high clock speed CPU (GHz), lots of cores)

**RAM Selection**

For a standalone server (the best configuration for Magento), the rule here is 2GB RAM/CPU Core. So if you have 8 cores, then 16GB RAM should be the minimum.

To work out what you need in addition to this, you need to factor in the size of your catalogue. Doing this is easy, multiply your number of store views against the total catalogue size.

Eg. In your case, 1 store view * 10,000 products = 10,000

My recommendation is,

<1,000    = 8GB   RAM
<50,000   = 16GB  RAM
<100,000  = 32GB  RAM
<100,000  = 32GB  RAM
<250,000  = 48GB  RAM
<500,000  = 64GB  RAM
<750,000  = 96GB  RAM

> 999,999  = 128GB RAM
>   You want to take the higher of the two numbers (ie. from the CPU Core:RAM ratio and catalogue requirements), or a sensible mix of the two.

**HDD Selection**

Lets make something clear, for the average Magento store (ie. <50k unique visitors/day), Magento is not bound by I/O - SSDs will not make your Magento store faster; it won't improve concurrency and it won't improve TTFB. Similarly, using striped RAID levels (eg. RAID10) will also provide no advantage (as almost every file on disk is going to be smaller than the stripe size anyway, so only a single disk will be used).

The only time storage is a bottleneck is on contended services (ie. cloud/VPS).

However, there are certainly advantages to fast I/O beyond the store operation itself. With SSDs, file operations (eg. Git/SVN status, backup/restore, copying directories etc.) are substantially faster. Your developer's life will be substantially easier (with routine tasks being much quicker).

Also note that not all disk drives are created equal.

```
Cheap/desktop-grade SSDs will perform slower than conventional HDDs
Cheap/desktop-grade HDDs will perform slower than enterprise HDDs
Cheap/desktop-grade HDDs will have poor NRE rates (usually 10^14) compared to enterprise disks (usually 10^16)
```

**Picking capacity is easy, you just need two commands,**

For the Magento document root

```
cd /path/to/magento/installation 
du -hsL . \
--exclude="/var/log" \
--exclude="/var/session" \
--exclude="/var/cache" \
--exclude="/var/full_page_cache" \
--exclude="/var/report" \
--exclude="/var/tmp" \
--exclude="/includes/src/"
```

For the MySQL DB

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(B.engine,'Total') "Storage Engine", CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.DSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Data Size", CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.ISize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Index Size", CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.TSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Table Size" FROM (SELECT engine,SUM(data_length) DSize,SUM(index_length) ISize,SUM(data_length+index_length) TSize 
FROM information_schema.tables 
  WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema') 
  AND engine IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY engine 
WITH ROLLUP) B,(SELECT 3 pw) A 
ORDER BY TSize;
```

Hope this will help you ;)

Comment: That is understood, I have a configuration of 4 cores with 16 GB RAM and over 200 GB (raid) disk storage. My front-end is almost fine as the page loads under 3-4 seconds completely with TTFB around 2 seconds (TTFB is concern here). For TTFB, we have optimized queries, used flat mode and written optimized code, but physical distance is very much. Our major clients are here in India while our server location is in US.
 My painpoint is the index management which is killing the service of the website. Whenever index management is in progress, the website almost comes to a halt.

Comment: never trust people who are multiplying cores to gigahertz... WTF??? `8 Cores @ 3.5GHz = 8 Cores @ 3.5GHz` ... no more no less...

Comment: Paul's RAM calculation is very stupid... Only the total database size matters here, the catalog size is absolutely irrelevant. also if you really grow, you better build some dynamic cluster/autoscaling... with RAM calculation like this the shop owner will get a heart attack...